# SELECT col1, COUNT(col2=0), AVG(col3) FROM table GROUP BY col1; in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, count, group-by

I have a table with three columns, I wanted the below query to work.

> SELECT col1, COUNT(col2=0), AVG(col3) FROM table GROUP BY col1;

what I'm trying to achieve is that I'm grouping by column 1, and in each row of the result, i want the following

1. col1
2. count of col2=0, grouped by col1, i.e i want to count number of rows in the table with col2==0 grouped by col1
3. average of col3 grouped by col1

but this is not working as I expect it to work.

COUNT(DISTINCT col2) will count the number of distinct col2 present in each group, what i want is count of col2 where it is zero in each group.

when I use the above query I'm just getting the normal COUNT without the equality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` for the conditional, and then SUM to get the number of 0 entries.

```
SELECT col1, SUM (CASE WHEN (col2=0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ), AVG(col3) FROM table GROUP BY col1;
```

Comment: wow thanks, sql is amazing, such a powerful tool, just realized today. Doing the same thing in python will be such a mess.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT col1, SUM (CASE WHEN (col2=0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ), AVG(col3) FROM table GROUP BY col1; 
The above query will give you average of all col3 grouped by col1 ..

select col1 ,count(col2),avg(col3) from table_name where col2==0 group by col1 ; 
this query will give you the average of respective rows in col3 where col2 is 0